# Full screen canvas for Chrome?

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, canvas

I'm trying to make a full screen canvas on Google Chrome.

```
<style>
#canvas:-webkit-full-screen {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}    
</style>
<button onclick="fullScreen()">Full Screen</button>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
    function fullScreen() {
        var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
        c.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
</script>
```

This code makes the canvas full screen, but only the height is full screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the CSS rule `fixed` for `position` with the canvas element:

```
position:fixed;
left:0;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

You might need to set `html` and `body` with width/height: 100% as well.

If you want to avoid zoom as this will give you, you would need to set the width and height of the canvas element directly (use `window.innerHeight` and `.innerWidth`).

Answer (score -1):

I do full screen canvas this way:

*More details can be found [here](https://gmer.io/c/t/learning_to_do_full_screen_canvas_html).*

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function refreshCanvas() {//refresh size canvas function
  document.body.style.width = window.innerWidth+'px';
  document.body.style.height = window.innerHeight+'px';
  canvas.setAttribute('width', window.innerWidth+'px');
  canvas.setAttribute('height', window.innerHeight+'px');
}
window.addEventListener('resize', refreshCanvas); //refresh when resize window
window.addEventListener('load', refreshCanvas); //refresh when load window
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
#mycanvas {
  background-image: url('https://gmer.io/resource/community/backgroundCanvas.png');
}
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```